# Event Messenger C++ Game Programming

Tags: c++, game

I'm using this Game Messenger as an instant messaging tool in my game. Just wondering peoples on thoughts on it.

Thank you!

```
    enum class eGameMessageType
{
    AddItemGUI = 0,
    RemoveItemGUI,
    UpdateSelectionBoxGUI,
    UpdateItemQuantityGUI,
    DestroyCubeSetPosition, 
    DestroyCubeReset,
    SelectedCubeSetPosition,
    SelectedCubeSetActive,
    SpawnPickup,
    PlayerDisgardPickup,
    AddToPlayerInventory,
    Max = AddToPlayerInventory
};

struct Listener : private NonCopyable
{
    Listener(const std::function<void(const void*)>& fp, const void* ownerAddress)
        : m_listener(fp),
        m_ownerAddress(ownerAddress)
    {
        assert(ownerAddress);
    }
    Listener(Listener&& rhs) noexcept
        : m_listener(rhs.m_listener),
        m_ownerAddress(rhs.m_ownerAddress)
    {
        rhs.m_listener = nullptr;
        rhs.m_ownerAddress = nullptr;
    }
    Listener& operator=(Listener&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        m_listener = rhs.m_listener;
        m_ownerAddress = rhs.m_ownerAddress;

        rhs.m_listener = nullptr;
        rhs.m_ownerAddress = nullptr;

        return *this;
    }

    std::function<void(const void*)> m_listener;
    const void* m_ownerAddress;
};

class GameMessenger : private NonCopyable, private NonMovable 
{
public:
    static GameMessenger& getInstance()
    {
        static GameMessenger instance;
        return instance;
    }

    template <typename GameMessage>
    void subscribe(const std::function<void(const GameMessage&)>& gameMessage, const void* ownerAddress)
    {
        auto& listeners = m_listeners[static_cast<int>(GameMessage::getType())];
        assert(!isOwnerAlreadyRegistered(listeners, GameMessage::getType(), ownerAddress));

        listeners.emplace_back(reinterpret_cast<std::function<void(const void*)> const&>(gameMessage), ownerAddress);
    }

    template <typename GameMessage>
    void unsubscribe(const void* ownerAddress)
    {
        auto& listeners = m_listeners[static_cast<int>(GameMessage::getType())];
        assert(isOwnerAlreadyRegistered(listeners, GameMessage::getType(), ownerAddress));

        auto iter = std::find_if(listeners.begin(), listeners.end(), [ownerAddress](const auto& listener)
        {
            return listener.m_ownerAddress == ownerAddress;
        });

        assert(iter != listeners.end());
        listeners.erase(iter);
    }

    template <typename GameMessage>
    void broadcast(GameMessage gameMessage)
    {
        const auto& listeners = m_listeners[static_cast<int>(GameMessage::getType())];
        for (const auto& listener : listeners)
        {
            reinterpret_cast<std::function<void(const GameMessage&)> const&>(listener.m_listener)(gameMessage);
        }
    }

private:
    GameMessenger() {}
    std::array<std::vector<Listener>, static_cast<size_t>(eGameMessageType::Max) + 1> m_listeners;

    bool isOwnerAlreadyRegistered(const std::vector<Listener>& listeners, eGameMessageType gameMessageType, const void* ownerAddress) const
    {
        assert(ownerAddress != nullptr);

        if (!listeners.empty())
        {
            auto result = std::find_if(listeners.cbegin(), listeners.cend(), [ownerAddress](const auto& listener)
            {
                return listener.m_ownerAddress == ownerAddress;
            });

            return result != listeners.cend();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Is this program made using a game engine?

Comment: It's from a little Minecraft clone that I made a while ago. It's only a pet project - am a student currently.

Comment: The thing is we don't have the definition of the class you derive from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Move `struct Listener` into `class GameMessenger`

The `struct Listener` is just an implementation detail of `GameMessenger`, you can move it into `class GameMessenger` like so:

```
class GameMessenger: ...
{
    struct Listener: ...
    {
         ...
    };

    ...
};
```

Now that it is `private`, I would also keep `Listener` very simple, and just have it hold the two member variables, without adding any member functions.

## Pass messages as `const` references

The actual message handler functions take a `const` reference to the message, but your `GameMessenger::broadcast()` takes it by value, making an unnecessary copy. Change it to:

```
void broadcast(const GameMessage &gameMessage) {...}
```

## Naming things

Some names could be improved. For example, `struct Listener` has a member variable `m_listener`. Combined with the `std::vector<Listener>`, you get the word `listener` repeated a lot, like in `GameMessenger::broadcast()`, where there's even a `listener.m_listener`. Consider renaming `m_listener` to `m_handler` or `m_callback`.

Some names are a bit longer than necessary. I suggest these changes:

```
- `typename GameMessage` -> `typename Message`
- `isOwnerAlreadyRegistered()` -> `isRegistered()`
```

## Make `class GameMessenger` a template

With `void` pointers you throw type-safety overboard, and requires you to `reinterpret_cast<>()` things. I can't say much about `m_ownerAddress`, however
the main problem here is that you have a non-templated `class GameMessenger`. Apart from the constructor, all the public member functions are `template <typename GameMessage>`. Instead of having one `GameMessenger` object being responsible for all possible message types, consider making the class templated itself, and only be responsible for one specific message type.

If you implement it this way, there will be one `GameMessenger` object per message type. That means there is no longer a need to have a `std::array` for each of the possible message types, and in fact `enum eGameMessageType` is no longer necessary.

Here is an example of how it might look:

```
template <typename Message>
class GameMessenger: private NonCopyable, private NonMovable 
{
    struct Listener {
        const std::function<void(const Message &)> m_handler;
        const void *m_ownerAddress;
    };

public:
    static GameMessenger& getInstance()
    {
        static GameMessenger instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void subscribe(const std::function<void(const Message&)>& handler, const void* ownerAddress)
    {
        assert(!isRegistered(ownerAddress));
        listeners.emplace_back(handler, ownerAddress);
    }

    template <typename Message>
    void unsubscribe(const void* ownerAddress)
    {
        auto iter = std::find_if(m_listeners.begin(), m_listeners.end(), [ownerAddress](const auto& listener)
        {
            return listener.m_ownerAddress == ownerAddress;
        });

        assert(iter != listeners.end());
        listeners.erase(iter);
    }

    void broadcast(const Message &message)
    {
        for (const auto& listener: m_listeners)
        {
            listener.m_handler(message);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<Listener> m_listeners;

    bool isRegistered(const void* ownerAddress) const
    {
        assert(ownerAddress != nullptr);

        auto result = std::find_if(listeners.cbegin(), listeners.cend(), [ownerAddress](const auto& listener)
        {
            return listener.m_ownerAddress == ownerAddress;
        });

        return result != listeners.cend();
    }
};
```

So how do you use it? Instead of writing:

```
void handleSpawnPickup(const SpawnPickupMessage &message) {...}
void *ownerAddress = ...;

auto messenger = GameMessenger.getInstance();
messenger.subscribe(handleSpawnPickup, ownerAddress);
```

You replace the last two lines with:

```
auto messenger = GameMessenger<SpawnPickupMessage>.getInstance();
messenger.subscribe(handleSpawnPickup, ownerAddress);
```

If you want to avoid having to explicitly mention the type when getting the messenger instance, consider writing an out-of-class function that subscribes to the right instance for you:

```
template<typename Message>
void subscribeToMessenger(const std::function<void(const Message&)>& handler, const void* ownerAddress)
{
    GameMessenger<Message>::getInstance().subscribe(handler, ownerAddress);
}
```

So that you can just write:

```
subscribeToMessenger(handleSpawnPickup, ownerAddress);
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you! I have responded with a follow up question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @G. Sliepen I have rectified the code but now have an issue where I have the public functions in GameMessenger that I'd like to make private or remove entirely - so the caller can only use the functions outside of class.

Just wondering the best way to do this? Thanks.

```
 template <typename Message>
    class GameMessenger : private NonCopyable, private NonMovable
    {
        struct Listener
        { 
            Listener(const std::function<void(const Message&)>& callback, const void* ownerAddress)
                : callback(callback),
                ownerAddress(ownerAddress)
            {}
    
            std::function<void(const Message&)> callback;
            const void* ownerAddress;
        };
    
    public:
        static GameMessenger<Message>& getInstance()
        {
            static GameMessenger<Message> instance;
            return instance;
        }
    
        void subscribe(const std::function<void(const Message&)>& callback, const void* ownerAddress)
        {
            assert(!isRegistered(ownerAddress));
            m_listeners.emplace_back(callback, ownerAddress);
        }   
    
        void unsubscribe(const void* ownerAddress)
        {
            assert(isRegistered(ownerAddress));
            auto listener = std::find_if(m_listeners.begin(), m_listeners.end(), [ownerAddress](const auto& listener)
            {
                return listener.ownerAddress == ownerAddress;
            });
            assert(listener != m_listeners.cend());
            m_listeners.erase(listener);
        }
    
        void broadcast(const Message& message) const
        {
            assert(!m_listeners.empty());
            for (const auto& listener : m_listeners)
            {
                listener.callback(message);
            }
        }
    
    private:
        GameMessenger() {}
    
        std::vector<Listener> m_listeners;
    
        bool isRegistered(const void* ownerAddress) const
        {
            auto listener = std::find_if(m_listeners.cbegin(), m_listeners.cend(), [ownerAddress](const auto& listener)
            {
                return listener.ownerAddress == ownerAddress;
            });
    
            return listener != m_listeners.cend();
        }
    };
    
    template <typename Message>
    void subscribeToMessenger(const std::function<void(const Message&)>& callback, const void* ownerAddress)
    {
        GameMessenger<Message>::getInstance().subscribe(callback, ownerAddress);
    }
    
    template <typename Message>
    void unsubscribeToMessenger(const void* ownerAddress)
    {
        GameMessenger<Message>::getInstance().unsubscribe(ownerAddress);
    }
    
    template <typename Message>
    void broadcastToMessenger(const Message& message)
    {
        GameMessenger<Message>::getInstance().broadcast(message);
    }
```

Comment: You can make everything in `GameMessenger` `private`, and add the following: `friend substribeToMessenger<>(const std::function<void(const Message&)>& callback, const void* ownerAddress);` And similar `friend` function definitions for `unsubscribeToMessenger()` and `broadcastToMessenger()`. This will allow the out-of-class functions to access the `private` member fucntions.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for some reason doing it like that. 

I can't access them with 'GameMessenger<Message>::getInstance().m_listeners' either.

Comment: It might be best to ask this on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) with a minimum reproducible example of what you tried.